# Does Bezout's Identity hold for Zero cases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

In some places I see Bezout's Identity stated for any two non-zero numbers $a$ and $b$. In other places it is stated that $a$ and $b$ are not both zero (so one of them can be). But doesn't Bezout's Identity hold for $a$ and $b$ both being zero, where it is assumed (as I see often done) that $gcd(0,0) = 0$? And if so, what is the reason for the non-zero constraint on one or both of the numbers?

Comment: Yes, it holds quite trivially, because $\gcd(a,0)=a$. In my opinion there's no reason for requiring one of the numbers to be different from zero.

Comment: Most people would require that the arguments for $\gcd$ cannot all be zero (it has something to do with the fact that $0$ has no greatest divisor and that the definition mentions the term "divisors").  However, there is an alternative way to define $\gcd$ without discussing divisors at all.  If you have a collection of integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, then you can define $\gcd\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots\right)$ to be the unique nonnegative integer $d$ such that $d\mathbb{Z}=\sum_{j}\,a_j\mathbb{Z}$.  If you accept this definition, then $\gcd(0,0,\ldots)=0$.

Comment: Provided you say $0|0$, then $0$ does have a greatest divisor, namely $0$ itself (and in fact then the non-negative integers become a complete lattice with respect to the divisor relation).